# Traverse a Map in Java Pythonically?

Tags: java, python, dictionary

I'm not really sure if "traversal" is the right word, but in Python, I can do this:

```
restaurantDict['menus'][menuIdx]['sections'][sectionIdx]['option_groups'][sectionOptionGroupIdx]['options'] = sectionOptionObjects
```

Is it possible to "traverse" a Map in Java in this style? Or is Python just wild and crazy like that?

Comment: How is this a traversal? You're just assigning to a nested dict.

Comment: If the keys and values of your `Map` allows it, *yes*. And is *yes* because for assignment you need to use `put` (in a `Map`) or call the right setter method, you cannot assign it directly.

Comment: It would be better if you could show us the Java code in question. Or, are you just looking for Java version of the Python sample?

Comment: a lot of `.get(key)` chained, and a `.put(key, value)` in the end.

Comment: Just use `get`. `restaurantDict.get("menus").get(menuIdx).get(...).put("options", sectionOptionObjects)`

Comment: I think you're looking more for method chaining.  I don't believe there is any way to do this straight out of the box with java Maps.  Edit:  I guess you could do this if you have a map of maps ... ect.  It would just be a lot more verbose than python.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible in Java. You just need to chain .get calls for all but the last key, and then call .put:

```
// Equivalent Python code: foo["a"]["b"]["c"] = "bar";
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>> foo = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>();
foo.get("a").get("b").put("c", "bar");
```

This is a fairly unpleasant thing to do in Java, because this isn't very idiomatic Java code.

Whereas Python encourages defining objects and their relations on the fly, good Java code lays out what kinds of objects you're dealing with in advance by defining appropriate classes. Stacking dicts might be OK in Python, but it makes for horrible Java.

Comment: +1. Although I have to admit that most things make for horrible Java.